# Is segregation inevitable in my unorthodox prison world?

Tags: society, alternate-worlds, survival, dungeons, criminal-underworld

I came up with this idea of creating this world, where the worst of the worst of a fantastic non-magical world are sent to this prison "realm" which keeps expanding chamber by chamber.

The story starts with the first-comers finding a dark room opening into a new area, and there is no certainty about when the next one will open.

In the current generation, they still don't know more than

- some rooms hold useful supplies
- some others hold grave dangers (Dragons, chimeras and big groups of enemies that a little party can't deal with and require a substantial amount of people to defeat it. I haven't thought exactly what, but the idea is to have really challenging creatures that in some cases have assured deaths like people having to act as cannon fodder and getting basically shredded to pieces, characters don't know what will it be but they are sure the hardship is assured) in them that may or may not give anything back in return for the dangers and their size is not determined.

I have dealt with the corpses by creating squads of criminals that take the corpses to distant chamber from the base camp.

The races I wanted to introduce into this world are orcs that live in isolated patriarchal societies where the strongest of them all leads as patriarch of the group and decides what will the group do, this patriarch is forced to accept any duel as demonstration of power and leadership, they are extremely smart and avoid external conflict and exiled orcs as they lose the order of the group start preying on any weaker being around that has anything valuable on them.

Goblins have the most human-like society as they live in big underground cities that no other race can enter but they constantly interact with other races through outposts set up in the surface where they trade goods and information that attracts people of all sides of the world and they are not eager to deal with any danger to their lifestyle.

Last but not least Slithereen are an underwater civilization that has not been seen in thousands of years and just recently woke from a long slumber the king of the depths imposed on them to save them from the poisonous environment that their world was turning into.  Their species are really fast learners and within a month of interacting with other races they are able to perfectly speak their language, but their devotion and love for their savior the king of the depths is something they will never leave behind.

**As there is more than one race living in there, is segregation something that is inevitable or will the dangers of the prison keep everyone together?**

Comment: This appears to be entirely opinion based. Maybe change your question to some specific problem you would like an answer to.

Comment: It sounds like you are playing with the concept of the Cube and asking a lot of opinion based questions. Side note: how can they lack knowledge of the size of the rooms but they can still manage to get corpse out of them?

Comment: The answer to 99% of all "Could there be..." questions is: "Yes". The answer to 99% of all "Should I put (X) into my world" questions is: if it serves the work and makes it interesting, add it. If it only pads things out without adding anything, leave it out.

Comment: they get the corpses into already looted rooms that are far away from the main base, they know where they are going but they dont know where will it expand next so areas where corpses are left turn later on into highly dangerous areas due to the decomposition of corpses, the size of the newly opened area may be a 4x4 room with a chest or a room that has a jungle-like biome that extends for kms, i try to have some freedom to create a high diversity of rooms and chambers, and thanks for editing i am a bit of a scrub in this

Comment: Welcome to the site, Luiso. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific, objective questions. Furthermore, we strongly discourage multiple questions per question post; such questions are often put on hold until an [edit] is made to limit the scope of question and answers. Feel free to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: Your new question is asking about an entire society, I'm afraid that's far too broad for us. Given a model like that books could be written about it.

Comment: @Separatrix i will do a few drafts and see what convinces me, as not everyone in the prison is human, there are orcs which are bigger and stronger and goblins that win strength in numbers i wouldnt know how to orientate a society that has something more than humans

Comment: @Luiso, human society is not homogeneous, consider the other species as caricatures of certain human societal classes and see where it gets you.

Comment: So it's been a VERY long time since I read it, but [Eternity (Eon) by Greg Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternity_(novel)) has a few similarities that might be useful? Basically there is an infinitely long tunnel, and the people inside of the tunnel can go through the walls into other places, some of which have resources, and some of which have dangers. It might be worth a skim.

Comment: I'd like to see this Q reopened.  It gives specific details & asks 1 question.  If anything, @Luiso it might help if you specified something about what are the species interned in the prison; that'd help people gauge whether it'd make sense to segregate or congregate.

Comment: thanks for the input @akaioi i just did the edit, i tried to escape archetypes for the species and im trying to make them feel unique one from another

Comment: This question has been nominated for reopening and I'm going to vote to do so.  While still a bit broad, I believe there's enough focus to address the birds-of-a-feather vs. brothers-in-arms vs bad-mutha-gangs etc. contexts in a deterministic fashion.  Cheers, mate, I'll be interested in the answers you get.

Comment: OP, to make the question even better, add some insight into what "grave dangers" are.  People (creatures) react to things, and it would help to know what they're reacting to.

Comment: @JBH the thinking is in progress but you can see in the edit i did the direction i want to take it in. basicaly powerful beings the realm warps in the chambers

Comment: "Birds of a feather flock together."  Yes, they'll segregate.  But... "the enemy of my enemy is my friend", so they'll work together when **sufficiently threatened** external force.

Comment: Besides, orcs and underwater creatures can't mix.